# "Vendesi" oppure "Vendonsi" appartamenti?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Girando per Milano ci sono tantissimi cartelli relativi ad appartamenti che sono in vendita (e che spesso restano invenduti per parecchio tempo). Quando questi appartamenti sono in un edificio di nuova costruzione, è facile che il cartello si riferisca a più di uno e qui inizia il mio dilemma.

Se la locuzione ***"Vendesi"*** deriva chiaramente dalla forma ***"Si vende"***, allo stesso modo, quando abbiamo a che fare con un sostantivo plurale, dobbiamo dire ***"Si vendono"*** da cui deriva ***"Vendonsi"***.

È però rarissimo che tale forma verbale venga utilizzata e di solito si trova il singolare impiegato anche per la vendita di più cose.

Sotto il profilo grammaticale so che tale forma è sbagliata, ma vorrei sapere se i testi di grammatica ed i dizionari iniziano a tollerarla oppure no.

Comment: *Vendonsi* is antiquate and terrible; why not using a plain *Si vendono* or *Si vende*?

Comment: @egreg: because `vendesi` is the standard form used in these cases? `Vendonsi` is less used but does not shock me too much, I actually quite like the sound.

Comment: @nico In written language the forms *dicesi*, *chiamasi* and similar used to be considered ‘good style’; classified ads were paid for word, so *vendesi* and *offresi* became standard in the commercial language. And grammar was not really looked for classified ads. I doubt there has ever been someone saying *vendonsi* instead of *si vendono* or, more simply, *vendo*.

Comment: @egreg: I am speaking of ads, not spoken language. I agree that you would not say vendesi in conversation, but the question is about writing ads, not speaking.

Comment: @nico *Vendesi* comes first, in alphabetical order, than *vendonsi*. This explains why it was used irrespective of the quantity of offered goods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il sito dell'Accademia della Crusca suggerisce che l'espressione "Vendonsi" sia meno usata, ma più corretta quando si parla di più appartamenti.

[Qui più informazioni](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/vendonsi-affittansi-consigli-linguistici).

> Va tuttavia considerato che, per una serie di motivi, è - e
>   probabilmente sarà sempre - più comune trovare le forme singolari
>   usate anche per il plurale. Su questo fatto incide certamente la
>   lessicalizzazione delle forme vendesi e affittasi, e il loro essere
>   diventate quasi un marchio pubblicitario (i cartelli degli annunci,
>   simili a quelli riportati in fondo a questa risposta, riportano quasi
>   esclusivamente queste forme, anche perché capita più spesso di dover
>   vendere o affittare una cosa per volta). Non dimentichiamo poi
>   l'usanza di impiegare il verbo al singolare anche per il plurale nel
>   caso di soggetti posposti

Answer (score 0):

Le frasi 'si vendono appartamenti' e 'si vende posto auto' sono entrambe forme passive, nelle quali rispettivamente *gli appartamenti* ed *il posto auto* sono i soggetti. Il verbo quindi deve concordare in numero e genere con essi.

Nelle forme portate ad esempio e' il 'si' a svolgere un ruolo passivante, si veda in proposito
http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/usi-funzioni-pronome-clitico-si.

Questa costruzione puo' essere fatta solo con la terza persona singolare e la terza persona plurale (o sesta persona) e prende appunto il nome di **si passivante**.

Puo' essere interessante ricordare che esistono, oltre a questa con il si passivante ed a quella piu' comune costruita con l'ausiliare *essere*, altre due costruzioni passive: sono quelle costruite con i verbi *andare* e *venire*, come in 'vengono venduti appartamenti' e 'questi appartamenti vanno venduti'.