# Problemi col “si” passivante

Tags: grammar, pronouns

"Se una cosa non c'è, si compra."

"Se mancano delle cose, allora si comprano."

Ritengo che queste due frasi siano corrette, ma spesso le vedo accompagnate da pronomi enclitici e proclitici.

Ecco alcuni esempi:

"Li si devono comprare"

"I cioccolatini sono buoni e si devono comprarli a tutti i costi"

"Se manca, lo si compra"

Potete aiutarmi a vederci chiaro sulla situazione?

Che io sappia il si passivante non regge certi pronomi.
Forse quello impersonale, ma che è solo singolare.

Ho molta confusione in testa.

Comment: Non capisco del tutto bene la tua domanda. Il dubbio è se queste costruzioni sono passivanti oppure impersonali? E poi come si deve combinare il "si" con i pronomi di oggetto diretto ("la", "lo", "li", "le", "mi", "ti", "ci", "vi")?

Comment: Ecco un esempio che ho tratto da un mio libro:  Si compra la penna. --> La si compra.

Comment: Parziale duplicato di questo, forse: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/can-si-passivante-be-constructed-with-null-subject-in-certain-contexts Trovi utili le risposte date lì, @Nakamura?

Comment: Potresti dare alla tua domanda un titolo che sia, in effetti, una domanda?

Comment: Dei tuoi esempi, i primi due non sono grammaticali: si direbbe rispettivamente “Li si deve comprare” e “...e li si deve comprare a tutti i costi”; come hanno già detto altri, in tutti e tre il “si” non è passivante bensì impersonale.

Comment: @DaG: È corretta la versione enclitica ma anche quella col pronome proclitico? Mi riferisco a  " si deve comprarli"".

Comment: @Nakamura: Il tuo dubbio è se il "si passivante" può essere accompagnato da un pronome di oggetto diretto ("la", "lo", "li", "le", "mi", "ti", "ci", "vi")? E come si deve combinare il "si" con i pronomi di oggetto diretto?

Comment: Sì, era questo, ma a quanto pare qiesta combinazione c'è solo col si impersonale.

Comment: @Nakamura: Potresti riformulare la tua domanda in modo che sia più chiara?

Comment: @Charo: Lo si deve comprare= si impersonale. Li si deve comprare= si impersonale. Si deve comprare= si passivante. Si devono comprare= si passivante. Io mi ero interrogato sulla possibilità di combinare il pronone atono con il si passivante, tipo " li si devono comprare/devono essere comprati". L'ho capito quando mi è stato da shullman che "li si devono comprare" non è corretto.  La differenza è davvero sottile. Comunque il mio dubbio era questo. Attendo una tua risposta 

Comment: Non sono italiana, quindi non sono la persona adatta per scrivere una risposta su questi aspetti della grammatica italiana che trovo particolarmente complicati. Tuttavia, per quanto posso capire dai miei libri, la costruzione che viene chiamata "si passivante" ha sempre esplicito un oggetto diretto, come in questi esempi che ho tratto da un mio libro: "Si mangia una mela. / Si mangiano due mele." Questo libro spiega che si chiama "si passivante" perché "questa costruzione con oggetto diretto è simile per significato alla costruzione passiva (*Una mela viene mangiata*)".

Comment: Sì, infatti era ciò che avevo dedotto da alcuni ragionamenti

Comment: Un titolo come “problemi col si passivante” è un po' troppo generico. Potresti per favore fare uno sforzo per renderlo più informativo?

Answer (score 1):

Credo che "si compra la penna" metta l'emfasi sulla penna. "La si compra" invece mette l'emfasi sul fatto che c'è un soggetto impersonale che la compra.

es 1: Al negozio si vendono tante penne  = A lot of pens are sold at the store.

es 2: Come si fa ad ottenere una penna? La si compra al negozio! = How does one obtain a pen? One buys it at the store!

Inoltre "Li si devono comprare" non mi sembra corretto. O si dice "si devono comprare delle penne" o si dice "li si deve comprare". Il secondo usa la coniugazione di terza persona singolare perché appunto qui abbiamo usato il soggetto impersonale che richiede il singolare sia in italiano che in inglese. ("one buys..."). Però hanno significati diversi che ***si possono vedere*** negli esempi e in questa frase.

Comment: Shulman: perché "lo si compra" sì  e "li si comprano" no? Il primo è singolare, il secondo plurale. Cosa cambia sostanzialmente da rendere impossibile la seconda?

Comment: Shulman: il si passivante non si può coniugare con i pronomi atoni, vero? Lo chiedo perché mi è venuto in mente visto che hai detto che " la si COMPRA" è corretto mentre, al plurale, "le si COMPRANO" è sbagliato, ma sarebbe giusto "le si COMPRA".  Da quel ricordo il si impersonale è solo singolare, quindi nelle mie frasi in cui erano presenti pronomi impersonali, ho usato il si impersonale, volendo invece usare quello passivante combinandolo con pronomi atoni (lo, la, le, li ecc..). Considerando la tua correzione tutto tornerebbe. Spero di essermi espresso bene.