# Perché usare il plurale "hanno" e non "ha" nella frase "Se si hanno bambini, questo agriturismo è l'ideale"?

Tags: verbs, agreement, grammatical-number

Come mai in questa frase si usa il verbo avere al plurale e non al singolare?

> "Se si **hanno** bambini, questo agriturismo è l'ideale"?

Forse è corretto anche "Se si ha bambini?"

Comment: Se si hanno dei bambini….se si ha un bambino…

Comment: @Hachi L'accordo nella forma impersonale non è così ovvio. Sono stati letteralmente scritti libri per analizzarlo!

Comment: @DenisNardin - mi puoi indicare qualcuno di  questi libri? Potrebbero essere utili ad analizzare la questione. Grazie

Comment: Ah credo di aver trovato il motivo - si tratta di un "si passivante" e non un "si impersonale". Con il "si passivante" abbiamo un oggetto diretto a cui va accordato il verbo. Si fa l'esercizio MA si fanno gli esercizi. È diverso dal tedesco dove con (man) il verbo rimane sempre alla terza singolare.

Comment: @Hachi Qualche tempo fa ho scritto una risposta che mi ha fatto scoprire che queste questioni sono molto più sottili di quello che uno pensa :) (https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/can-si-passivante-be-constructed-with-null-subject-in-certain-contexts/9622#9622)

Comment: Quindi questa domanda è un duplicate.

Comment: Può essere utile anche questo: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/usi-e-funzioni-del-pronome-clitico-si/173 Non mi pare che sia stato citato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come hai detto tu stesso in un commento, si tratta di un *si* passivante.

Baso la mia risposta nel contenuto del libro *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo (edizioni ELI). In un costrutto con *si* e un verbo transitivo, quando c'è presente quello che sarebbe il complemento oggetto logico del verbo, questo oggetto diventa il soggetto grammaticale della frase. Per questa ragione, tale costrutto si chiama *si passivante* e il verbo in terza persona si accorda al singolare o al plurale a seconda del numero del soggetto grammaticale che segue. Ecco alcuni esempi presenti nel libro:

> **Si parla** italiano. 
> **Si parlano** diverse lingue.

Altri esempi tratti dallo stesso libro in cui si vede come l'ausiliare *essere* in tempi composti si accorda in genere e numeroal soggetto grammaticale della frase:

> Si è mangiat**o** un dolce. 
> Si è mangiat**a** la torta. 
> Si sono mangiat**i** molti dolci. 
> Si sono mangiat**e** molte torte.

Quindi, il tuo esempio è in effetti

> Se **si hanno** bambini, questo agriturismo è l'ideale

con il verbo *avere* accordato con il soggetto *bambini*.

Answer (score -3):

Assolutamente no. Il verbo è riferito a bambini che è plurale.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più approfondita e argomentata. Suggeriamo di provare a leggere le pagine [tour] e [help] e di dare un'occhiata alle altre domande e risposte per capire come il sito funziona. Non esitare a chiedere aiuto se ne hai bisogno.