"Si deve stare attenti" - why is "attenti" plural?
My Italian grammar book tells me that adjectives must always agree with the attaching noun or pronoun in gender and number.
In si deve stare attenti it seems to me that si is singular because the conjugation is deve. Why then is attenti plural? Alternatively, if si is not singular, why isn't the conjugation devono?

I’m voting to close this question because “si is singular” is wrong, so the whole question is meaningless.

@DaG I've covered that in my question. "Alternatively [i.e. if si is not singular], why isn't the conjugation devono?". I've edited to make this explicit. The question isn't meaningless to me otherwise I wouldn't be asking it. It's also not as obvious as you are making it sound, because a native speaker I asked before posting here couldn't explain it. If you know the answer, please post it. Voting to close a question just because a poster's initial understanding is "wrong", instead of just explaining why it's wrong, is unhelpful. All language learnings are going to be wrong at some point.

@DaG Furthermore, my grammar book (Modern Italian Grammar, 3rd edition) has this to say (emphasis mine): "the si impersonale structure, equivalent of English ‘one’, is often confused with
si passivante. Whereas the si passivante is always used with a transitive verb,
and has both singular and plural forms, the si impersonale is used with an intransitive verb and is only singular.". I think the fact that there exists a grammar book which disagrees with you makes this a reasonable question to ask, and if the book is wrong then explaining why can form the basis of an answer.

It doesn't disagree with me. A specific use of “si” is singular, but “si”, in itself, is certainly not singular: it has several uses, plural, singular, impersonal, reflexive and so on (some of them already covered in other Q&A here). But it is well possible that I misunderstood your question. Could you rephrase it in a more neutral way, without mentioning some “rule” to which this would be an “exception” and so on?

By the way, did you check similar questions, such as 1, 2, 3? Or perhaps I'm wrong and your question is not similar. If so, why?

@DaG I gave the specific phrase that I'm having difficulty with ("si deve stare attenti"), so I'm not sure how I could further specify which use of "si" I'm concerned with. I even said that si is singular "in si deve stare attenti and never claimed it was singular in general. In the sentence "si deve stare attenti", why does "deve" imply that it is singular, while "attenti" implies that it plural? I'm not trying to be difficult here; I genuinely don't know how to word my question any clearer than that. I will delete the final paragraph if that is causing confusion.

Ok, thanks. Perhaps I'm the one being overly difficult. That “singular” made me react knee-jerkly. But have you had a chance to have a look at questions like https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/can-si-passivante-be-constructed-with-null-subject-in-certain-contexts ? Some fine points of reflexive and passivante “si” are already discussed there.

To me the question is clear and makes sense: Why is "si deve stare attenti" correct? We could expect to have "si deve stare attento" or "si devono stare attenti", ma in "si deve stare attenti" it seems there is a mismatch between the singular "deve" and the plural "attenti". In all questions mentioned by @Dag I didn't see a similar issue. In my opinion this question deserves a specific answer (unless there are other questions in SE mentioning this issue).

@Bruno : My bad: as an Italian I don't get that “We could expect to have [those agreements]”, but if this sounds weird to a foreigner, it's useful to address it. By the way, the issue is actually mentioned in at least one of the answers to the last question  I mentioned (for instance: “L'accordo è al plurale anche quando il predicato nominale è un aggettivo («si è allegri» o «allegre») e con i verbi passivi («si è lodati» o «lodate»)” and so on), but of course if someone can give a more thorough answer, why not.

@DaG I missed this answer. The OP would probably be satisfied with this answer. The problem is that the questions are different, so it is not easy to find it. Maybe could you repeat this answer here with a link to the previous answer?

It's a normal use of "si"-impersonale.
Also "Quando si è giovani, si è spensierati." is correct.
Il "si" wants the 3rd person singolare for the verb but it is normal to use the plural form for the adjective.
https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/usi-e-funzioni-del-pronome-clitico-si/173
